# advanced custom field not return back result

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, author

i am using advanced custom filed and i made custom author field (it could be Publisher Or Brand etc) now this author's name is not printing on product (Book) page . in custom field its for author's name slug is 'names'

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', "ACF_product_content", 10 );

    function ACF_product_content(){

      echo '<h2> ACF Content </h2>';

      if (function_exists('the_field')){
        echo '<p>Woohoo, the_field function exists! </p>';

        //the_field('authors');

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(get_the_ID());
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r(get_field('authors'));
        echo '</pre>';

        die;
      }

    }
```

for this i got the result
[Check this report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4CkA.jpg)

. now problem is to show the Authors name which is ['post_title'] in this array.
i tried so many solutions but not working its not showing the result.
i used to show this result by this code

`echo the_field('names');`

'names' is the field name in 'Authors' custom field.

Comment: Isn't easier to just copy&paste the text here, in the question, than taking a screenshot, uploading it to an image-hosting service and pasting the URL here?

Answer (score 1):

try this code for ACF

```
<?php
echo get_field('your custom filed slug name',get_the_ID());
?>
```

fetch the post title

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

for display author name for below function

```
<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
```

Comment: not working. i used "print_r(get_the_ID());" this code and its printing the id

Comment: yes, it is get id. for title use this function echo get_the_title();

Comment: yes this one is working and i got the title for post but.

Comment: did you saw my attached image [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4CkA.jpg

Comment: yes, as per the screen shot you can get the post title by using this function get_the_title() and i can not see the authors field in this screen shot. so it is not working your code. get_field('authors')

Comment: you can get the author name by using echo get_the_author();  this function

Comment: now check here you can see the complete detail.

[link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Lx8.jpg[link]

Comment: its showing me error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function eget_field()

Comment: mistake in your function "eget_field()" . use this   " echo get_field('authors',get_the_ID()); " please check
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: sorry my mistake. i got the ID only in return.

Comment: if(get_field('authors')){

  $fields = get_field('authors');
   foreach($fields as $field) {
       $author_name = $field->post_title;
       echo 'Writer: '.$author_name;
   };
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of the methods below .  You have to strictly set $post otherwise `get_the_ID()` funtion return `false`.

```
    global = $post;
    $custom_key = 'author';
    $post_id = get_the_ID();



    echo $customer_key_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $custom_key , true );
```

OR

```
    global = $post;
    $custom_key = 'author';
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $custom_values = get_post_custom_values( $custom_key , $post_id );

    foreach ( $custom_values as $key => $value ) {
       echo "$key  => $value <br />"; 
    }
```

Comment: @alt4uraj What the key  name for the custom field you want to get ?

Comment: i think , you custom key name seems to be 'author_name' , so replace $custom_key variable value with  'author_name'

Comment: thanks my problem is solved i got the answer:
if(get_field('authors')){

  $fields = get_field('authors');
   foreach($fields as $field) {
       $author_name = $field->post_title;
       echo 'Writer: '.$author_name;
   };
  }
}